# Dynamic multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Is it appropriate to call dynamic multidimesional array, an array of arrays?

```
int **mp = 0;

// Create an array of pointers
mp = new int*[6];

// Where each element of type pointer, points to dynamic array.
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    mp[x] = new int[7];
```

Looking at this, I would say they are array of pointers pointing to arrays of size 7 ints.
But are dynamic arrays even considered arrays or just a chuck of memory returned by pointer?

Comment: uhh that should be `x < 6` not `x < 7`.  `mp[6]` is invalid.

Comment: What does `arrays of memory` mean? `memory` is not an entity, or object.

Comment: Even then `arrays of dynamic memory` wouldn't make sense. `arrays of int` makes sense, `arrays of char*` makes sense, `arrays of std::vector<std::string>` makes sense. But `arrays of memory` doesn't make sense unless you define a user-defined type called `memory`.

Comment: Thanks, I should knew it. But In the context, I wasn't even considering them arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is about semantics.  As far as the standard is concerned, `new []` does create an array, but returns a pointer to the first element.  From 5.3.4/5 of the standard:

> When the allocated object is an array
>   ... the new-expression yields a
>   pointer to the initial element (if
>   any) of the array.

So in your case, what we colloquially call "an array of arrays" is really an array of pointers, which is distinct from e.g. `int x[6][6]`, which is truly an array of arrays.

Comment: Is there really a pointer to array decay conversion goes on when the array is created?

Comment: @user: It depends what you mean by "really"!  Under the hood, the memory-allocation part of `new` is probably just a wrapper for `malloc()`.  But semantically, the standard thinks of it as creating an array.  So in that sense, yes, I guess it could be considered as array-to-pointer decay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are arrays of pointers. Arrays of arrays are different:

```
// array of 6 pointers into one-dimensional arrays 7 elements each
int** mp = new int*[6];
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    mp[x] = new int[7];

// array of 6 arrays of 7 elements each (two-dimensional 6x6 array)
// (all dimensions except the 1st must be known at compile time)
int (*mp)[7] = new int[6][7];
// or, more commonly, when all dimensions are known at compile time,
int mp[6][7];
```

Arrays of pointers are commonly used in C since there is no other way to create multi-indexed data structures at run time in that language.

Comment: +1 for the nice example of how to dynamically obtain a true array of arrays (well, a pointer to the first element of it, anyhow).

Answer (score 0):

C++ (and C) treat ragged arrays and contiguous multidimensional arrays quite differently. Access an element appears to be the same, but is quite different underneath the hood.

```
void do_something (
    double matrix[3][3],
    double ** ragged_array)
{
    double x = matrix[1][2];
    double y = ragged_array[1][2];
    ...
}
```

The first access requires going through a pointer only once while the second requires going through two pointers.

Comment: This is 100% correct, but I'm not sure it addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think of arrays as pointers, because in practice a variable that holds an array is just a pointer to the first element of the array. Furthermore, you can use **operator[]** in any pointer, even if it's not pointing to an array.
With that line of thought:

*mp* is a pointer to a "chunk of integer pointers", and *mp[x]* is a pointer to a "chunk of integers".

Now, these "chunks of memory" is what I would think of as the array, so you've got:

*mp* is a pointer to an array of integer pointers, and *mp[x]* is a pointer to an array of integers.

In your example you've got a total of 7 arrays (chunks of memory), one for every *new* statement. Don't forget to *delete[]* every one of them after you're done using the structure.

Comment: Obligatory -1 for "a variable that holds an array is just a pointer to the first element".

Comment: If I was being purist I would agree with you. However, the fact that you can't obtain (at least not to my knowledge) from such a variable information about if it is holding an array or not, you could, in practice, consider it a pointer.

Comment: There are several ways in which arrays and pointers are not the same.  e.g. using `sizeof`, assignment, passing to functions, pointer arithmetic, the fact that a `T[][]` cannot be converted to a `T**`, etc.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: You are absolutely correct. I didn't consider `sizeof` as a means of determining if a "pointer" is an array.